# AngularJS testing service results in 'UnknownProvider'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I know there's a lot of similar questions out there, and I've gone through a lot of them, but none of them seem to be resolving my issue.

I'm trying to test a Service and I keep getting the `Unknown Provider` error and I just can't figure it out.

The code looks like this:

## TestService.js

```
'use strict';
angular.module('app')
    .service('TestService', function() {

        var testFunction = function() {
            console.log('testFunction');
        };

        return {
            testFunction: testFunction
        };
    });
```

## test.service.tests.js

```
'use strict';
describe('TestService', function() {

    beforeEach(module('app'));

    var TestService;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_TestService_) {
        TestService = _TestService_;
    }));

    describe('testFunction', function() {
        it('Should call the test function', function() {
            expect(TestService.testFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
});
```

Even if I comment out the `expect(testService.testFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();` I still get:

`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: TestServiceProvider <- TestService`

I can't figure this out. I don't know if it's something wrong with this code or if I just don't have test set up properly.

Anyway, any help is appreciated.

Comment: refer to this link: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr

Comment: Thanks, I've been through that doc before and double checked all the possible reasons for the error that it outlines, but none of them seem to resolve the error :(

Comment: but i think problem is with its unable to resolve a required dependency

Comment: Oh shit you're right, there was a dependency in the service that was the problem! Awesome. Post as answer and I'll accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is with required dependency. make sure the dependency is defined and spelled correctly

refer below link:

[docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr)